# binary_cross_entropy_with_logits produces negative output

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am developing a machine learning model to detect bones from a skeleton image.
I am using pytorch, and the model i am using is the [hourglass model](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-hourglass-networks-to-understand-human-poses-1e40e349fa15).

When i use binary_cross_entropy_with_logits i can see the loss decrease, but when i try to test the model, i notice that:

1. **The output is never greater than zero**.
2. The output is just incorrect (the bones are not detected).

This is how i am calling binary_cross_entropy_with_logits

- `loss =  F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(ouputs[i], Y, weight=Mask, reduction='sum') / Mask.sum()`

This is how i am doing testing

```
ouput = model(X)
ouput_sig = torch.sigmoid(ouput)
plot_voxel2d(ouput_soft1)
```

The exact same model, inputs, targets work if i use the mse loss like this:

```
loss = torch.sum(((ouputs[i] -  Y) ** 2) * Mask) / torch.sum(Mask)
```

I made sure the target is between 0 and 1.
Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it the output of the model that is negative, or the loss?

Comment: its the actual output its self, i tried playing around with the weight initialisation,  i can get the output to be positive for a few iterations, but it goes back to -ve.   ``nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0, 1)``

Comment: What is your model, how is it defined? Are you applying sigmoid on your output? I would assume this has nothing to do with neither your optimizer nor the weight initialization.

Comment: its is this: https://github.com/zhan-xu/AnimSkelVolNet/blob/master/models3D/model3d_hg.py#L164

Comment: I noticed that as long as Sigmoid is involved, i  don't get convergence so if i use MSELoss it works. but if i use MSELoss with sigmoid as final layer, it does not work.  The layer before the final layer looks like: Conv3d -> BatchNorm3d -> ReLU -> Dropout3d -> Conv3d

Answer (score 0):

The following code block is proposed by G. Hinton in his course: [http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Etijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf)

```
optimizer = optim.RMSprop(net.parameters(), lr=0.005, weight_decay=1e-8)
if net.n_classes > 1:
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
else:
    criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

Then you will need to use sigmoid (Torch Functional: `F.sigmoid`) in a similar manner as the code example below:

```
for isample, sample in enumerate(ds):
    
    mask_torch = net2(sample['image'][None, :, :, :].type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor))
    mask = (F.sigmoid(mask_torch.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)) > 0.4925099).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    print(mask)
 
    for ichan in range(3):
        ax[isample, ichan].imshow(sample['image'][ichan].cpu())
        
    ax[isample, 3].imshow(sample['mask'][0].cpu())
    ax[isample, 4].imshow(mask[0, 0].cpu().detach().numpy())
```

Place the sigmoid at the end after al the layers. It will look something like this:

For sigmoid, It will look something like this:

```
def forward(self, x):
    #print(x.shape)
    x = self.layer_1(x)
    x = self.layer_2(x)
    x = self.layer_3(x)
   
    logits = F.sigmoid(self.outc(x))
    
    return logits
```

Comment: Hi Joe thanks for the suggestion, will play around with RMSprop, and see if it works

Comment: I noticed that as long as Sigmoid is involved, i  don't get convergence so if i use MSELoss it works. but if i use MSELoss with sigmoid as final layer, it does not work.  The layer before the final layer looks like: Conv3d -> BatchNorm3d -> ReLU -> Dropout3d -> Conv3d

Comment: Sigmoid should only come once and last after all the layers.

Comment: I edited the code above to provide what your forward pass might look like, if you only have 3 layers.

Comment: @whyme: Have you been able to fix it?

Comment: ahh, dont "settle" make it work right/better :)

Comment: also - @whyme plz mark answer correct for others, as this is taken from a repo of mine that works, the answer isnt "wrong".

Comment: I am testing ``F.binary_cross_entropy(torch.clamp(ouputs[i], 0, 1), Y, weight=Mask, reduction='sum') / Mask.sum()`` which gives better results, not as good MSELoss yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this multiple times, each time reason was labels are not between 0 and 1